# Vuelayers vl-style-icon syntax

Tags: vuejs2, vuelayers

I've been looking through the vuelayers documentation and have found little info on to use the vl-style-icon module, which is quite important if you want to create icons on your vuelayer map.

I'm pretty sure I have proper syntax when it comes to using it but `marker.png` won't load in through it. I've tried accessing it as just a normal image and it works fine so it is to my assumption that it's something with my syntax.

**Here is my code:**

```
<template>
  <vl-map :load-tiles-while-animating="true" :load-tiles-while-interacting="true" style="height: 400px">
    <vl-view :zoom.sync="zoom" :center.sync="center" :rotation.sync="rotation" projection="EPSG:4326"></vl-view>
    <vl-feature v-for="crime in crimePoints" :key="crime.id">
      <vl-geom-point :coordinates="crime.coords"></vl-geom-point>
      <vl-style-box>
        <vl-style-icon src="./marker.png" :scale="0.4" :anchor="[0.5, 1]"></vl-style-icon>
      </vl-style-box>
    </vl-feature>
    <vl-layer-tile>
      <vl-source-osm></vl-source-osm>
    </vl-layer-tile>
  </vl-map>
</template>
```

`vl-style-box` and `vl-style-icon` are the main points here. I have also checked to see if the points come up without `vl-style-box` and they do. What could be wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried using @ to refer to the icon? `src="@/marker.png" ` or maybe `src="../marker.png" `

Comment: Both tried, and the marker.png file is also in the same directory as the vue file

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
<vl-style-icon :src="require('./marker.png')" :scale="0.4" :anchor="[0.5, 1]"></vl-style-icon>
  </vl-style-box>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used Vue CLI to create your vue project include this in your **vue.config.js** file. First section tells webpack to parse url attribute on custom tags other than what is already configured ([Source](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#inspecting-the-project-s-webpack-config)).

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module.rule('vue').use('vue-loader').tap(options => {
      options.transformAssetUrls = {
        'vl-style-icon': 'src',
        ...options.transformAssetUrls,
      };
      return options;
    });
  }
}
```

Run the following command to verify the correct vue-loader configuration is there
[Source](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#inspecting-the-project-s-webpack-config)

```
vue inspect > output.js
```